# JMeter Report Dashboard

Tags: jmeter, performance, csv-file

Most recent version of JMeter has an option to generate [Report Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) which is great, but i am struggling to customize it to match my needs.

I am running performance tests for every new version of Application.

Lets start from current state of my reports.
I have User-Defined Variable named - Version. I am changing this for every new run of performance test.
Also, there is time stamp as a second type of comparison. - It is possible to compare previous results of the same version. Basically results from yesterday compare to today's results.

I am using [Flexible File Writer](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/) to save results to csv file. Using this plugin, it is perfectly easy to store version number(User-Defined variable) in every row, which is important for next step.

Results are imported to Excel Pivot table from where you can do basically everything.

Now, this above is ok, but it would be great to have created consolidated report directly from JMeter but there are few problems here. 
Report Dashboard is created from JMeter log file and here comes problems:

1. How to pass User-Defined Variable to log file?
2. How to make JMeter to continue with adding results to log file? 
   Currently it is asking to write new filename, so one test-one log file and i need: few tests-one log file.
3. How to Modify Jmeter properties to be able to compare results of more versions/more dates using JMeter [JMeter Report Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)? thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the answers:

1. In order to add a JMeter Variable to .jtl log file define `sample_variables` property like:

   - Permanent way: add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in JMeter's "bin" folder)

     ```
     sample_variables=yourVar
     ```

     JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up. On next execution you will see `${yourVar}` value added as a separate new column to .jtl results file
   - Temporary way: pass the property via `-J` command line argument like:

     ```
     jmeter -Jsample_variables=yourVar -n -t ......
     ```

   References:

   - [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)
   - [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
2. You can use `-l` command line option to specify output .jtl results file name. So in order to get results of 2 tests into single file just provide the same .jtl output name like:

   > jmeter -n -t test1.jmx -l **result.jtl**
   >
   > jmeter -n -t test2.jmx -l **result.jtl**

   Reference:

   - [Non-GUI Mode (Command Line mode)](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
3. It is not possible to compare different test run reports using the Reporting Dashboard (unless you develop this functionality yourself). You can consider using an external service like [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/) for that.